# map() returns an iterator that yelds numpy arrays. How to convert it in a numpy array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am using a `map` function where each element pointed by the returned iterator is a `numpy` array, i.e.

```
result = list(map(func, values))
print(result[:2]))
[array([0.981, 0.23]),  array([1.231, -0.56])]
```

I wish the result to be a unique `numpy` array, i.e.

```
print(result[:2])
array([[0.981, 0.23],[1.231, -0.56]])
```

I tried to use `result = np.fromiter(map(func, values))` but I get the following deprecation warning:

```
 DeprecationWarning: Conversion of
 an array with ndim > 0 to a scalar is deprecated, and will error in future. Ensure you extract a single
 element from your array before performing this operation. (Deprecated NumPy 1.25.)
```

How to solve the problem?

EDIT: although I had good answers, I would like to convert to np.array directly from the returned iterator from `map`, thus skipping the conversion from iterator to iterable.

EDIT2: Here is a minimum working example

```
def func(u):
    # The size of A,B,C,D may change, so it is good idea to keep the function as general as possible
    A = np.array([[-1, 0], [-0.2, 1]]).reshape(2, 2)
    B = np.array([1, 0]).reshape(2, 1)
    C = np.array([[1, 0], [0, 1]]).reshape(2, 2)
    D = np.array([1, 1]).reshape(2, 1)

    xx = A @ xx + B @ u
    return C @ xx + D @ u


N = 100
values = np.ones(N).reshape(N, 1)
result = np.array(list(map(func, values)))
```

Comment: what's wrong with `np.array(result)`?

Comment: What annoys me is the first conversion from iterator to iterable (i.e. from map to list). I would like the conversion to the final np.array to happen directly from the iterator and I found this np.fromiter function but it gives me the deprecation warning message.

Comment: @Barzi2001 please can you give us the details about `func` and `values`?

Comment: @Goku main question edited!

Comment: @Barzi2001  thanks.. if you are getting a warning you can still use. I am looking for alternatives for `np.fromiter`. It is giving warning for multidimensional arrays.

Comment: In your example `map` is NOT returning a list of lists, but an iterator that yields Numpy's arrays, and in general `map` does not return a list of objects but an iterator that yields objects. You may consider the idea of changing your title.

Comment: `fromiter` clearly states `Create a new 1-dimensional array`. It does have a reputation of being a bit faster than `np.array` on a list, but at least part of that comes from less flexibility in handling higher dimensions. I prefer the expressiveness of list comprehensions over `map` so haven't pushed the limits of `fromiter`.

Comment: `fromiter` has a recent change with respect to `dtype`.  The answer you don't like highlights this.

Comment: I was going to write a full answer but ran into a couple of problems.  Your `func` with `matmul` has an undefined variable `x`.  So I can't make a realistic guess as to what it returns.  And when using `np.fromiter` as you show, I get a missing `dtype` parameter error.  The docs are clear that `dtype` is required, and `count` is desireable for it work efficiently (it avoids multiple calls to the `resize` method).

Comment: Apologies. ‘x’ should be  ‘xx’.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your value by:

```
result = list(map(func, values))
print(result[:2]))
[array([0.981, 0.23]),  array([1.231, -0.56])]
```

---

```
np.stack(result[:2], axis=0 )

#output

array([[ 0.981,  0.23 ],
       [ 1.231, -0.56 ]])
```

Or

```
np.vstack(result[:2])

#output

array([[ 0.981,  0.23 ],
       [ 1.231, -0.56 ]])
```

Or

```
np.array(result[:2])

#output

array([[ 0.981,  0.23 ],
       [ 1.231, -0.56 ]])
```

---

Also. you can use list comprehension instead of `list,map`

It depends upon your `func` and `values`. Something like:

```
result = [func(x) for x in values]
```

Comment: Nice! But then I have to concatenate np.vstack(list(map(..))) which is very tedious. Is there any other method?

Comment: try this and let me know `np.array(list(map(func, values))[2:])`

Comment: It also work with `np.array(list(...` but what annoys me is the first conversion from iterator to iterable (i.e. from `map` to `list`). I would like the conversion to  the final np.array to happen directly from the iterator and I found this `np.fromiter` function but it gives me the deprecation warning message. Shall I edit my original question to add this further detail?

Comment: What is your numpy version?

Comment: numpy version 1.25.2 installed through conda-forge.

Answer (score 1):

Use of `np.array(list(map(func,values)))` is a good general call, though I often prefer `np.array([func(i) for i in values])`.  In any case, `np.array` gets a list argument which it can analyze and determine the correct dtype and shape.  It creates a target array, and fills in values, with any necessary conversions.

If the list is 'ragged' in some way of other it 'punts', sometimes making an `object` dtype array, now raising a somewhat obscured error about inhomogeneous inputs.

`fromiter` is supposed to streamline this for the case of a 1d input with a **defined** `dtype`.  It doesn't have to look at the whole list to identify the best `dtype`; you tell it that.  And with `count` it can make the array with `np.empty(count, dtype)`.  Without `count`, it makes a guess, and does one more more `resize` method calls to adjust that target.

You are pushing the documented boundaries of how `fromiter` can be used.

Misuse with a range interable:

```
In [79]: np.fromiter(range(3))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[79], line 1
----> 1 np.fromiter(range(3))

TypeError: fromiter() missing required argument 'dtype' (pos 2)
```

correct use with dtype:

```
In [80]: np.fromiter(range(3),int)
Out[80]: array([0, 1, 2])
```

or with a comprehension generator:

```
In [81]: np.fromiter((i+3 for i in range(3)),int)
Out[81]: array([3, 4, 5])
```

Trying to return arrays, but leaving the dtype as scalar `int`:

```
In [82]: np.fromiter((np.array([1,2])+i for i in range(3)),int)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[82], line 1
----> 1 np.fromiter((np.array([1,2])+i for i in range(3)),int)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Taking advantage to recent patch that allows object dtype:

```
In [83]: np.fromiter((np.array([1,2])+i for i in range(3)),object)
Out[83]: array([array([1, 2]), array([2, 3]), array([3, 4])], dtype=object)
```

or with the lightly documented subarray dtype:

```
In [88]: np.fromiter((np.array([1,2])+i for i in range(3)), np.dtype((int,2)))
Out[88]: 
array([[1, 2], 
       [2, 3],
       [3, 4]])
```

Note this will only work if we can specify as part of the `dtype` the length of arrays that the iterable returns.

Casting this as a mappable function:

```
In [90]: def foo(x): return np.array([1,2])+x

In [91]: list(map(foo, range(3)))
Out[91]: [array([1, 2]), array([2, 3]), array([3, 4])]
```

Given a list of arrays, `np.array` tries as a default to make a multidimensional numeric dtype array:

```
In [92]: np.array(list(map(foo, range(3))))
Out[92]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [3, 4]])
```

We can get object dtype arrays from this with `frompyfunc` and `vectorize`:

```
In [93]: np.frompyfunc(foo,1,1)(np.arange(3))
Out[93]: array([array([1, 2]), array([2, 3]), array([3, 4])], dtype=object)

In [94]: np.vectorize(foo, otypes=[object])(np.arange(3))
Out[94]: array([array([1, 2]), array([2, 3]), array([3, 4])], dtype=object)
```

### edit

Bewary of putting too much hope on performance improvements with `fromiter` and generators/map.  These still involve python level iteration.

Our `foo` can be done with in 'pure' numpy with broadcasting like:

```
In [95]: np.array([1,2])+np.arange(3)[:,None]
Out[95]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [3, 4]])
```

(though for this small size the iteration might still be faster.)

Your `func` with `@` might be expressible without iteration, using the `batch` behavior of 3d+ arrays in `matmul`.  But that's another topic.

Answer (score 0):

Executing

```
import numpy as np 

def f(t): return np.array((t*0.3, t/0.3))
res = np.fromiter(map(f, (2, 3)), dtype=np.dtype((float, 2)))
print(res)
```

shows

```
[[ 0.6         6.66666667]
 [ 0.9        10.        ]]
```

[Numpy manual on fromiter](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html#:%7E:text=A%20carefully%20constructed,%5B5%2C%206%5D%5D)